# Android: Issue with ScollView and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I am creating UI like as per below code

View pager with images and then other UI controls.
It is working fine with 2-3 controls, but if UI is out of page with 10 UI controls then scroll view not wokring.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/scheduleViewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/create_account_create_password" />

                // Other UI controls

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: You can make fragments for the viewpager and make separate xml for each fragment which will contain scrollview while in main.xml only view pager is needed.

Comment: I think you should calculate height of your root layout inside `ScrollView` programmatically. Try to set height of that view larger than your device screen size for example: 1000dp with 10 UI controls and let me know if `ScrollView` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this below code ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/scheduleViewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/create_account_create_password" />

            // Other UI controls
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```